# Does ADFS 3.0 honor the Subject attribute sent in SAML Request?

Tags: request, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

According to the SAML2.0 specification, the service provider can send the Subject value in the SAML request, it sends to the IDP. This informs the IDP about the identity, the service provider needs to authenticate. But IDP has right either to honor either honor this or not. I am looking to know if ADFS honor this.

We are looking for a way to skip asking user to enter username at ADFS authentication, if the SAML request already contained it as Subject attribute.

Comment: I'm wondering about this too. I'll keep digging.

Comment: I found the answer later. ADFS does not honor Subject attribute in this manner as of now.

Comment: If there is a request for this, please add to the user voice forum for ADFS. https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/304621-active-directory/category/141126-adfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer later. ADFS does not honor Subject attribute in this manner as of now.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling upon this, ADFS does not honor the subject, but you CAN pass the email / username using a regular query parameter:

> Interesting. We support this if you send query parameters &username= or &login_hint= today. AAD uses this to send this to ADFS. It should work over SAML protocol as well.

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/304621-active-directory/suggestions/33404725-saml-subject-from-authnrequest